# Obtaining different weather forecasts from the Environment Canada website

Tags: c#, parsing

Here is the code I use to get the different weather forecasts from the Environment Canada website:

```
 public static void Main()
 {
   string url = "http://dd.weather.gc.ca/nowcasting/matrices/SCRIBE.NWCSTG." + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.HH") + "Z.n.Z";
   string allStations = Decompress.zDecompress(url).ToString();
   string temp = allStations.Substring(allStations.IndexOf("STN: CYYC"));
   string weatherReports = temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf("+\n."));
   string[] lines = weatherReports.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
   Station s = new Station();
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
     if (line.IndexOf("-") != 0 && line.IndexOf("STN") != 0 && line.IndexOf("DATE") != 0)
        {
          Weather w = new Weather();
          string[] properties = line.Split('|');
          for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
              {
               properties[i] = properties[i].Trim();
                if (properties[i] == ""){
                    properties[i] = "0";
                }
              }
           w.SkyCover = int.Parse(properties[1].Trim());
           w.Ceiling = int.Parse(properties[2].Trim());
           w.Pcpn1 = properties[3].Trim();
           w.Pop1 = int.Parse(properties[4].Trim());
           w.Pcpn2 = properties[5].Trim();
           w.Pop2 = int.Parse(properties[6].Trim());
           w.Pcpn3 = properties[7].Trim();
           w.Pop3 = int.Parse(properties[8].Trim());
           w.Pop = int.Parse(properties[9].Trim());
           w.PcpnQuantity = double.Parse(properties[10].Trim());
           w.PcpnType = properties[11].Trim();
           w.Temperature = double.Parse(properties[12].Trim());
           w.DewPoint = double.Parse(properties[13].Trim());
           w.WindDirection = int.Parse(properties[14].Trim());
           w.WindSpeed = int.Parse(properties[15].Trim());
           w.GustSpeed = int.Parse(properties[16].Trim());
           w.Visibility = double.Parse(properties[17].Trim());
           w.VisObstacleType = properties[18].Trim();
           s.Reports.Add(w);
}}}
```

And here is what the string looks like after my substrings:

> ```
> STN: CYYC    |SKY|CIG|        PRECIPITATION        |POP|   ACC  |    TEMP   |    WIND   |  VIS   |
> \nDATE      HR |/10|   |PCPN1|POP|PCPN2|POP|PCPN3|POP|   | Qp | Tp|  T  |  Td | DD| VV|GST|(SM) |TP|
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+--+
> \n20150805 0600|  8|140| -RW |100|     |  0|     |  0| 60| 0.0|   | 13.0| 10.0|  0|  0|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 0700|  8| 92|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0|  0| 0.0|   | 13.0| 11.0|290|  9|   |10.00|  |
> \n20150805 0800|  9| 82|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0|  0| 0.0|   | 13.0| 11.0|  0|  0|   |15.00|  |
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+--+
> \n20150805 0900|  6| 91|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0|  0| 0.0|   | 13.0| 10.0|  0|  0|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 1000|  8| 84|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0|  0| 0.0|   | 13.0| 11.0|230|  8|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 1100| 10|113| -RW |100|     |  0|     |  0|100| 0.1| RA| 13.0| 11.0|277| 11|   |10.00|  |
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+--+
> \n20150805 1200| 10| 93| -RW |100|     |  0|     |  0|100| 0.1| RA| 13.0| 10.8|225|  9|   | 7.00|  |
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+--+
> \n20150805 1300|  8|999| -RW |100|     |  0|     |  0| 33| 0.1| RA| 13.9| 11.4|163|  6|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 1400|  8|999| -RW |100|     |  0|     |  0| 31| 0.1| RA| 14.4| 11.5|129|  7|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 1500|  8|999| -RW |100|     |  0|     |  0| 26| 0.0|   | 14.9| 11.6|134| 12|   |15.00|  |
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+--+
> \n20150805 1600|  9|999|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0| 12| 0.0|   | 15.5| 11.4|196|  6|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 1700|  5|   |     |  0|     |  0|     |  0| 12| 0.0|   | 16.1| 11.0|289|  8|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 1800| 10|999|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0| 10| 0.0|   | 16.7| 10.7|335| 15|   |15.00|  |
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+--+
> \n20150805 1900| 10|999|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0| 13| 0.0|   | 16.7| 10.2|353| 17|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 2000|  9|999|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0| 17| 0.0|   | 17.1| 10.1|349| 18|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 2100| 10|999|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0| 18| 0.0|   | 17.5| 10.0|346| 20|   |15.00|  |
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+--+
> \n20150805 2200|  8|999|     |  0|     |  0|     |  0| 21| 0.0|   | 17.2| 10.4|354| 19|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150805 2300| 10|999| -RW | 80| -T  | 20|     |  0| 24| 0.3| RA| 16.9| 10.9|  3| 18|   |15.00|  |
> \n20150806 0000| 10|999| -RW | 60| -T  | 40|     |  0| 24| 1.6| RA| 16.6| 11.4| 13| 18|   |15.00|  |
> \n-------------+---+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+---+---+----+---+-----+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+.
> ```

Before my substrings, this string is repeated for every stations (a few hundred stations) and I use the `STN: CODE` and `+.` delimeter to isolate my desired station(CYYC here). Is there a better way to do the substrings and to assign the values to my weather objects?

Comment: Are you on .Net 3.5 or above? The code looks quite old fashioned (IMO) so just wanted to check that you're not limited to .Net 2.0 before I answer

Comment: @RobH According to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` I have v4.0.30319 , I don't have admin rights and only visual studio express for web, so I don't think I have any other way of looking what version I am running (no visual studio command prompt either).

Comment: It's in the properties of the project (i.e. right click => properties => Application => Target Framework) It sounds like you just file new'd a console app so will be .Net 4 by the looks of it. I'll answer in a mo

Comment: @RobH .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Single responsibility

Each method should have one clear responsibility. Your code is doing a lot of different things all in one method - the entry point of the application no less. Add in some additional methods to make things clearer:

For example:

```
private static string GetFullWeatherReport()
{
    string url = string.Format("http://dd.weather.gc.ca/nowcasting/matrices/SCRIBE.NWCSTG.{0:MM.dd.HH}Z.n.Z", DateTime.Now);
    return Decompress.zDecompress(url).ToString();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetStationReports()
{
    // There appears to be a line with a only a dot between stations
    return GetFullWeatherReport().Split(new[] { "\n.\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
}
```

That means you can now replace the first few lines of Main:

```
public static void Main()
{
     IEnumerable<string> stationReports = GetStationReports();
     var cyycReport = stationReports.FirstOrDefault(r => r.StartsWith("STN: CYYC"));
     foreach (var line in GetDataRows(cyycReport))
     {
         // ParseWeatherReport();
     }
} 

private static IEnumerable<string> GetDataRows(string weatherReport)
{
    return weatherReport.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(IsDataRow);
}

private static bool IsDataRow(string reportLine)
{
    return !reportLine.StartsWith("-") && !reportLine.StartsWith("DATE") && !reportLine.StartsWith("STN");
}
```

Keep going through the code and extracting methods so that you can read Main like a book - I think a good rule of thumb is whether or not a non-programmer has a decent chance of figuring out what's happening.

## LINQ

I introduced a new concept or two into your code, one of which was LINQ. I can't explain the full magic of LINQ adequately so I enourage you to go and do some reading on it. The central concept is IEnumerable and a set of extension methods like `Select`, `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`.

For example:

```
string[] properties = line.Split('|');
for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
{
    properties[i] = properties[i].Trim();
    if (properties[i] == ""){
        properties[i] = "0";
    }
}
```

Could become:

```
 string[] lines = line.Split('|').Select(s => s.Trim()).Select(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "0" : s).ToArray();
```

## var

If the type of an assignment is obvious, I prefer to use `var` e.g.

```
var welcomeMessage = "Hello!";
```

vs

```
string welcomeMessage = "Hello!";
```

I hope that's a useful start - all code typed directly into browser so apologies if it doesn't compile!

Comment: I've done LINQ 2 years ago, but I didn't do enough to think about using it when the opportunity arises. That's exactly the kind of answer I expected though thanks! Is there any advantage to using var?

Comment: Nice write up.  Your `GetDataRows` has likely typo: `cyycReport.Split` should probably be `weatherReport.Split`.

Comment: @RickDavin - thanks: loli has done the honours :)